# Redet man den Weihnachtsmann mit "Du" oder mit "Sie" an?

Tags: formality

Hier in den USA gibt es eine Werbung für Rosetta Stone im Fernsehen.  Ein deutscher Junge will mit Santa Claus reden und es stellt sich heraus, dass Santa auch Deutsch kann.

Der Junge sagt, "Du sprichst auch Deutsch?!".  Würde ein Junge nicht *"Sie"* verwenden, wenn er Santa anredet?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Abgesehen, dass dass ich nicht verstehe, weshalb die Frage irrelevant sein soll: Die Geschichte, dass der Weihnachtsmann eine Erfindung von Coca Cola sei, stimmt so nicht. Siehe: http://textakademie.de/index.php?id=933

Comment: Jemdanden, der "schon immer" Jahr für Jahr durch den Kamin hereingerauscht kommt und als gern gesehener Gast Milch und Kekse kriegt, wird man wohl als Freund der Familie ansehen und duzen dürfen ...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Deinen Kulturkampf in allen Ehren (Ich für meinen Teil bin froh, dass der Weihnachtsmann kaum religiösen Ballast mit sich trägt, weniger glaubwürdig ist er auch nicht), aber das führt doch weit an der Frage vorbei.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Du hast gleich mal Coca-Cola reingebracht, obwohl das vollkommen daneben liegt. Und dann noch seitenweise Kommentare.. Das hier sollte in den Chat ausgelagert werden, es bringt die berechtigte Frage, ob der Weihnachtsmann geduzt würde oder nicht, schließlich nicht weiter und stört nur.

Comment: Wer gerade kleine Kinder beobachtet, weiß ohnehin, dass die *niemanden* siezen, egal ob es sich nun um Fabelwesen oder Frau Müller von nebenan handelt. Erwachsene würden den Weihnachtsmann/Nikolaus im Beisein ihrer Kinder aber tendentiell auch duzen.

Comment: Und weil die ganze Diskussion offensichtlich müßig ist: uuuund weg. Weil es jedoch eine Beantwortung der Frage darstellt: Nein, Kinder duzen zunächst einmal jeden, vor allem Fabelwesen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Santa Claus wird im Deutschen einfach 'der Weihnachtsmann' genannt, und alle duzen ihn, auch die Erwachsenen, falls diese sich dazu herablassen, den Weihnachtsmann persönlich anzureden. Mutter zu Dennis: »Schreib mal einen Brief an den Weihnachtsmann.« – Dennis: »Ja, gut.«

> Lieber Weihnachtsmann,
>
> ich wünsche mir eine Million Euro, ein Furzkissen und dass Mama und
>   Papa aufhören zu streiten.  Wie immer war ich sehr brav und sehe
>   keinen Grund,  weshalb du mir diese Wünsche abschlagen könntest.
>
> Dein Dennis.

Answer (score 8):

Setzt man den Nikolaus - immerhin ein Bischof - mit dem Weihnachtsmann gleich, bleibt es beim Du, wie aus einem Kinderlied hervorgeht:

> Sei gegrüßt, lieber Nikolaus
>   wieder gehst Du von Haus zu Haus
>   alle Kinder lieben Dich
>   warten schon und freuen sich

Answer (score 7):

Nachdem in allen Liedern und Gedichten sowohl der Weihnachtsmann als auch der Nikolaus geduzt werden, eine Formulierung mit "Sie" zumindest mir noch nicht untergekommen ist, würde ich davon ausgehen dass jedes Kind "Du" verwenden würde.

Zum Beispiel *Lieber, guter Weihnachtsmann, zieh die langen Stiefel an, kämme deinen weißen Bart, mach' dich auf die Weihnachtsfahrt.* (aus einem Kommentar von [Thorsten Dittmar](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2072/thorsten-dittmar))

Comment: Ein paar Zitate als Beleg wären nicht schlecht.

Answer (score 5):

Ich weiß jetzt nicht, wie alt der Junge denn ist. Aber oft duzen kleine Kinder ihren Gegenüber. Nicht aus Unhöflichkeit, sondern einfach aus Unwissenheit um die Sie-Form.

Answer (score 5):

Nachdem in mehreren Antworten schon genauer ausgeführt wurde, dass der Weihnachtsmann in der Tat geduzt wird, sollte man vielleicht auch noch erklären, warum. Während sehr junge Kinder noch alle Menschen unterschiedslos duzen, würden die meisten älteren Kinder normalerweise jeden fremden alten Mann mit weißem Rauschebart siezen – nur eben nicht, wenn sie ihn als den Weihnachtsmann (oder Nikolaus) verkörpernd akzeptieren.

Grund dafür ist wohl, dass die Einführung der Höflichkeitsform die (konservativere) Sphäre von imaginären und religiösen Charakteren erst ganz zuletzt erreicht. Insbesondere wird im Deutschen ausnahmslos auch Gott geduzt. Auch zur Zeit des Shakespeare- und King-James-Bible-Englisch, als das Englische noch zwischen Singular *thou = du* und dem als Höflichkeitsform verwendeten Plural *you = ihr* unterschied, wurde Gott immer mit *thou* angesprochen. (Z.B. "Thou knowest, Lord, the secrets of our hearts.")

Answer (score 4):

Jeder darf seine unsichtbaren Freunde anreden wie er/sie will. Dafür gibt es keine Regeln, schon gar keine grammatischen.

Für Christen ist das höchste und erfurchtgebietendste Wesen, das überhaupt vorstellbar ist, Gott. Und sogar den sprechen sie auf Deutsch mit Du an:

> Oh Herr, gib uns deinen Frieden.
>   Nicht: <del>Oh Herr, geben Sie uns Ihren Frieden.</del>

Und wenn man Gott gewohnheitsmäßig duzt, darf man das auch mit dem Osterhasen, der Zahnfee und dem Weihnachtsmann machen.

Comment: So alt, wie viele Bibeltexte sind, wäre ich fast eher von »Oh Herr, gebt uns Euren Frieden« ausgegangen; das korrumpiert aber nicht die Aussage, die dahintersteht. +1.

Comment: @Jan: Das ist kein Bibeltext. Der lateinische Satz »Da pacem Domine«, dessen deutsche Übersetzung »Oh Herr, gib uns deinen Frieden« ist, stammt aus der christlichen Liturgie. Es ist ein Teil des Antiphons (Gegengesangs) des Introitus (Einzugsgesangs) des 18. Sonntags nach Pfingsten (also des 24. Sonntags des Kirchenjahres). Der Satz geht zwar auf den 121. Psalm der Vulgata zurück, steht so aber nicht in der Bibel.

Comment: Nicht nur "Herr", "Gott" oder Jesus werden geduzt, sondern grundsätzlich alle Heiligen. Damit auch der Nikolaus (siehe auch Antwort von @domsom ), oder dieser Tage auch (der heilige) Martin (von Tours). [Allerheiligenlitanei](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allerheiligenlitanei#Text_der_Litanei)